# How to make substring-matching query work fast on a large table?

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, substring, text-search

I have a large table with a text field, and want to make queries to this table, to find records that contain a given substring, using ILIKE. It works perfectly on small tables, but in my case it is a rather time-consuming operation, and I need it work fast, because I use it in a live-search field in my website. Any ideas would be appreciated...

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17633344/is-there-a-way-to-index-in-postgres-for-fast-substring-searches

Answer (score 1):

Check [Waiting for 9.1 – Faster LIKE/ILIKE](http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2011/02/19/waiting-for-9-1-faster-likeilike/) blog post from [depesz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/80168/depesz) for a solution using trigrams.

You'd need to use yet unreleased Postgresql 9.1 for this. And your writes would be much slower then, as trigram indexes are huge.

Full text search [suggested by user12861](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122697/how-to-make-substring-matching-query-work-fast-on-a-large-table/7123419#7123419) would help only if you're searching for words, not substrings.

Comment: I have tried trigrams and found that a) The index is enormalously huge b) The speed of search is too slow. I tried to create a table that contains all the possible substrings of all the words. The amount of the records is even more large, but search became faster. Still, it thinks sometimes more than 10 seconds on queries containing 1-2 characters. I don't know what to do :(

Comment: You'll not get any faster for 1-2 character queries. Because such a query will have to return significant percentage of rows no index will help you.

Comment: @Tometzky: Though your statement seems to ring true when you think about it, I still wonder how programs like everything (http://www.voidtools.com/) do it, because there appears to be no slowdown whatsoever, no matter what wildcard string.

Comment: This Everything program filters filenames. There's at most several hundred thousands of them in any given computer - very small database. It can display on screen only several tens of them at any given time - it can stop searching very early and continue when needed (for example when user scrolls). If you add " limit 30" to your 1-2 characters query it will also be fast.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look into full text indexing.  It's a bit complicated, maybe someone else can give a better description, or you might try some links, like this one for example:
http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Full_Text_Indexing_with_PostgreSQL