# Is there a way to index in postgres for fast substring searches

Tags: postgresql

I have a database and want to be able to look up in a table a search that's something like:
select * from table where column like "abc%def%ghi"
or
select * from table where column like "%def%ghi"
Is there a way to index the column so that this isn't too slow?

Edit:
Can I also clarify that the database is read only and won't be updated often.

Answer (score 32):

Options for text search and indexing include:

- [full-text indexing](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch.html) with dictionary based search, including support for prefix-search, eg `to_tsvector(mycol) @@ to_tsquery('search:*')`
- [`text_pattern_ops` indexes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-opclass.html) to support prefix string matches eg `LIKE 'abc%'` but *not* infix searches like `%blah%`;. A `reverse()`d index may be used for suffix searching.
- [`pg_tgrm` trigram indexes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html) on newer versions [as demonstrated in this recent dba.stackexchange.com post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46328/inconsistent-query-execution-times-using-trigram-indexes).
- An external search and indexing tool like [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/).

From the minimal information given above, I'd say that only a trigram index will be able to help you, since you're doing infix searches on a string and not looking for dictionary words. Unfortunately, trigram indexes are *huge* and rather inefficient; don't expect some kind of magical performance boost, and keep in mind that they take a lot of work for the database engine to build and keep up to date.

Comment: The 'reverse()d index' refers to an index built on an expression, i.e. 'reverse(col)' in this case. I didn't realize this was possible. Another use case for this mechanism is case-insensitive search by indexing 'lower(col)'.

Answer (score 11):

If you need just to, for instance, get unique substrings in an entire table, you can create a substring index:

```
CREATE INDEX  i_test_sbstr ON tablename (substring(columname, 5, 3)); 
-- start at position 5, go for 3 characters

It is important that the substring() parameters in the index definition are
the same as you use in your query.
```

ref: http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/BANLkTinjUhGMc985QhDHKunHadM0MsGhjg@mail.gmail.com

Answer (score 6):

For the `like` operator use one of the operator classes `varchar_pattern_ops` or `text_pattern_ops`

```
create index test_index on test_table (col varchar_pattern_ops);
```

That will only work if the pattern does not start with a `%` in which case another strategy is required.

Comment: If full-text searching is needed, [pg_trgm](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html) might work. I've used it in the past and it works pretty well under certain conditions. It should be noted that the indexes get quite large. IIRC, about 2.5x the size of the indexed column.